# Using Volley to send JsonObject with Children

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanna send a notification using Volley to FCM.
The method expects to get the message information under "data".
The problem is that when i use "put" in volley - like here:

```
    JSONObject notificationTitleObject = new JSONObject().put("message_title",notificationTitle);
```

The line above is deleted from "data".
I have tried to use JsonArray and then putting it as the value of "data".
It didn't work.

If I was writing the desirable result in Json, it will look like that:

```
    { "data": {
    "message_title": "XXXX",
    "message": "XXXXX"
    "message_image_url": "XXX"
  },
  "to" : "/topics/Notifications_For_Event_Items"
}
```

The full code is here:

```
 private void sendNotifToServer() throws JSONException {

        rootObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notificationTitleObject = new JSONObject().put("message_title",notificationTitle);
        JSONObject notificationMessageObject = new JSONObject().put("message",itemName.getText().toString());
        JSONObject notificationImageObject = new JSONObject().put("message_image_url",imageUrl);
        try {
            rootObject.put("to","/topics/Notifications_For_Event_Items");
            rootObject.put("data",notificationTitleObject);
            rootObject.put("data",notificationMessageObject);
            rootObject.put("data",notificationImageObject);
//            rootObject.put("data",new JSONObject().put("fragmentType","1"));

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddEventItemsActivity.this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, notificationUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return rootObject.toString().getBytes();
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization","key="+notifApiKey);
                return headers;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct `JSONObject` is the following:

```
rootObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject();
dataObject.put("message_title", notificationTitle);
dataObject.put("message", itemName.getText().toString());
dataObject.put("message_image_url", imageUrl);

rootObject.put("data", dataObject);
rootObject.put("to","/topics/Notifications_For_Event_Items");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are amazing! I haven't seen it !

Comment: Glad I helped. Please upvote/mark as correct if this answers your question

Comment: Cannot up-vote unfortunately, but I have marked it as the correct answer :)